# How to set a proxy to disconnect an application from network?

Tags: networking, proxy, ip, port, http-proxy

I'm trying to disconnect some application from network using its proxy configuration.

I tested random `ip` and `port` values in my Mozilla Firefox browser but Firefox continues to open pages normally. Is there any special values to be entered to make sure it will not access internet.

(What I want is to find this solution from proxy configs not using firewall or external applications to block network access.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a firefox extension called blocksite.

Here is the detailed [instructions](http://www.wikihow.com/Block-Websites-on-Firefox) about the usage of blocksite extension. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: This is a good blocker tool but I need to disconnect firefox (or other applications) from its proxy configs, neither by addons nor tools nor external blocking features of windows nor external firewall.

Comment: @ideal4ever, you can configure a wrong proxy IP address and the port number. So that firefox will start sending request to the wrong IP and port number hence no response.

I just tried and found **The proxy server is refusing connections**

Comment: This is what I wanted and I tried too. But my firefox works with wrong proxy!

Comment: Let me check on that, is there a way you can reset your firefox to factory default and test? Or grab a new VM install a fresh OS and try with firefox wrong proxy. I am not sure is this a firefox issue or windows settings issue. If you configure wrong proxy then firefox should return the error.

Comment: You're right. I disabled a firefox plugin named `AutoProxy` and now entering wrong `IP`/`Port` is protecting pages to be opened. It seems plugin is not working as expected when I disable it from its options and It overrides firefox proxy settings. Thanks for your helps.